# Encryption using BouncyCastle's Elliptic Curve Crypto API in Java

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I am looking for a sample code to Encrypt/decrypt a byte[] using 'ECKey' in bouncy-castle's java implimentation. Especially i need to know how to specify Algorithm, padding etc.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is too low-level an API for you to use unless you already understand elliptic curve cryptography. If you insist you should probably use the `IESEngine` class. This takes a `BasicAgreement` object, and `ECDHBasicAgreement` is an example of this. That is where your elliptic curve stuff comes into play. And no, I'm not giving you sample code.

Comment: Don't forget to followup or accept your questions, Aslam.

Answer (score 2):

For this time only, as the sample source still cannot be downloaded separately. This is just the code of the internal bouncy castle samples. Download the latest sources or look up the EC IES test [here](http://www.koders.com/java/fid33E10C31D0C65B6922AFAF45F0FFB8218C052FE9.aspx) (just googled that).

Comment: Note that EC encryption is almost always used in combination with a fast symmetric cipher, and the EC public key only encrypts the random session key.

Answer (score 2):

In BouncyCastle API is IESEngine (Integrated Encryption Scheme) that uses a BasicAgreement and KDF objects the example you can find it in [ECIESTest.java](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/adecd89d33edf278a5c601af2de696f0a6f65251/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/ECIESTest.java). It shows in detail the use of this class.